# How can we open another software and fill in a field with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am going to make a software which take a link and open IDM and put link to idm to download

My question is : how can i do something to open IDM and put link to idm?

Comment: Okay well all you would need from pyqt would be the interface to get the information you need --- then you would use straight python to open the IDM does your IDM have an API or would you need to use a command line like script to do that?

Comment: there is an api : http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/idm_api.html but i does not tell anything about python , and i don't want to use command line , i wanna make interface for it